# Adding scanf and EOF to program

Tags: c, scanf, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char string[100];
   int c = 0, count[26] = {0};
   int accum = 0;

   printf("Enter a string\n");
   gets(string);

   while ( string[c] != '\0' )
   {

      if ( string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z' ){
         count[string[c]-'a']++;
         accum++;
      }

      else if (string[c] >= 'A' && string[c] <= 'Z'){
          count[string[c]-'A']++;
          accum++;
      }
      c++;
   }

   for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )
   {
      if( count[c] != 0 )
          printf( "%c %f\n", c+'a', ((double)count[c])/accum);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

This should be an easy question, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Right now, I have the print statement "Enter a string".  I want to change it so that the user can keep inputting a string using scanf instead of printf until EOF is reached.  Basically I want to remove the "Enter a string" statement and just have input a string until EOF and then have the letter frequency run once on all the strings inputted.  How would I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want behavior similar to what you'd get if this were run over and over until EOF (of the console?), but only needing to run the program once?

Comment: Basically the program is to keep inputting strings using scanf until EOF and then count the letter frequencies of all the strings inputted.

Comment: never, ever, use `gets`. This dangerous and has been withdrawn from POSIX and C standards. Use `fgets`, instead.

Comment: this line: ((double)count[c])/accum) is dividing a smaller number by the total number of numbers.  I.E. the result would be less than one. However this code is using an integer divide, so when ever the divisor is greater than the divided, the result will always be 0

Answer (score 1):

To do this using `scanf()` for input.

`scanf()` returns EOF when the EOF condition or IO error occurs.

```
 // printf("Enter a string\n");
 char ch;
 while (scanf("%c", &ch) == 1) {  
   if ( ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' ){
     count[ch-'a']++;
     accum++;
   }
   ...
 }
```

Using `int ch = fgetc(stdin)` would make more sense.

---

> "The `fscanf` function returns the value of the macro `EOF` if an input failure occurs
>   before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the
>   number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in
>   the event of an early matching failure." C11dr §7.21.6.2 16

Answer (score 0):

Add your printf and gets statements inside the while loop

```
printf("Enter a string\n");
gets(string);

while ( string[c] != '\0' )
{
     ...//remaining code inside while loop

     printf("Enter a string\n");
     gets(string);

}
... //for loop code and return 0;
```

Comment: How can I do it with scanf? And do I not need to add the EOF?

Comment: change gets to  scanf ("%s",string); http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Comment: Okay , what about the EOF part? @userDEV

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I zeroed the variables for each loop. And I treated a blank entry (just press Enter) as EOF. But if you wanted the statistics for all the strings, don't zero the values at the start of the `while` loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char string[100];
    int c = 0, count[26] = {0};
    int accum = 0;

    do {
        c = 0;
        accum = 0;
        memset (count, sizeof count, 0);

        gets(string);
        if (strlen (string) < 1)
            break;      // terminate

        while ( string[c] != '\0' ) {
            if ( string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z' ) {
                count[string[c]-'a']++;
                accum++;
                }

            else if (string[c] >= 'A' && string[c] <= 'Z') {
                count[string[c]-'A']++;
                accum++;
                }
            c++;
            }

        for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ ) {
            if( count[c] != 0 )
                printf( "%c %f\n", c+'a', ((double)count[c])/accum);
            }
        }
    while (1);

    return 0;
}
```